# How to make a cross domain post (from googledrive to google docs forms)?

Tags: forms, google-docs, google-drive-api

I have created a new form in google docs and then I've hosted an html in the google drive. The link of the post location is: docs.google.com, the link of the hosted html is googledrive.com.

How I make communicate each other?

Comment: This is an important question, imho. Google Drive hosting combined with content from Google docs could be a really useful poor man's CMS.  However, the same-origin-policy means that links in embedded google docs (in an iframe) don't work as expected.  A clean cross-browser solution would be very useful.